# Docker Engine starts but Docker Desktop does not open (windows 10)

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

when I try to open docker desktop nothing happens, I execute docker commands on powershell and notice they work, so I tested throwing commands before trying to open docker desktop and they fail with the typical error about docker engine not running, so I try to open docker desktop nothing happens but the commands now work on powershell, what could this be? It started happening today, I have docker desktop 4.24.2 (it autoupgrades). I am using a corporate laptop

**EDIT**:

Been searching for answers but nothing, also if I run this command `wsl -l -v` in powershell I see this:

[image]

So no idea why the docker desktop UI is not starting/opening, also there is no icon in the task bar of the little whale with the containers

Have restarted pc, only thing I have not tried is uninstalling docker desktop and reinstalling it because I would lose all my images that I have already pulled so yeah would be the last resource...

Comment: Have you tried to update WSL in PowerShell? you can do that by running `wsl --update` in PowerSell.

Comment: Hi, the most recent version is already installed, that is the msg I get from it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the only way to fix this was unninstalling docker desktop and reinstalling it, lost all my images, have to pull them again